# javascript: "everything has finished drawing to the screen" event?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, browser

Is there a javascript event I can hook into that will let me know when everything has finished drawing to the browser screen? Images, backgrounds, and DOM elements with proper CSS.

I am setting up some "loading..." divs that should disappear only when the page is perfect and ready to be shown to the user.

I am aware of $(document).ready and onLoad, but these are not what I mean.

I am using angularJS, but I dont think this should matter.

thanks!

Comment: [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) (and the jQuery wrapper you've specified) certainly won't help... but what is it about [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) that _doesn't_ suit your needs?

Comment: The load event is raised once all images and external resources are loaded. Careful though, this includes third-party scripts, which can be slow to load at times.

Comment: window.onload should be suffice.

Comment: onload won't work with a dynamic app using something like AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, $(document).ready only waits for HTML structure and Javascript to load to trigger.

You better use :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //do stuff here
});
```

to wait for everything in your page to load (even pictures)

Answer (score 0):

Though this solution will not trigger any event, it should help you.

Define CSS like this:

```
#dvLoading
{
   background:#000 url(images/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1000;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

Use the above in

```
<div id="dvLoading"></div>
```

And then do this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/ssqtH/embedded/result/

Source:http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/show-loading-image-while-page-is.html

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using AngularJS, I can assume that your images and content are mostly loaded dynamically, in which case you cannot (easily) know when exactly all your content is even generated, and hence you'd also have no idea when all your images will be loaded since everything will be loaded asynchronously.

What you could do is have your DOM placeholders for widgets/apps/controllers be set to a loading-like state by default (a loading.gif maybe?) and when Angular generates the content it will just replace it. Look at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations for how to implement animations on certain directives.

Then within those widgets/apps/controllers you would have to do the same thing with the content within them...

So basically it's a cascading "loading screen", where each level of your application loads up like a water fountain.

Answer (score -1):

What is wrong with the $(document).ready or onLoad functionality?

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    $(".loading").hide();
}
```

Comment: This only indicates the DOM is ready. Not that all images have loaded, etc.

Comment: @JonathanSampson My mistake, corrected it to be `$(window).load(...)`